# Apply Different leaf node styles at same level in Treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I am in need of showing a directory structure using tree view control dynamically.I am able to get the tree view but there is a problem with styles. My tree view looks this.

[image]

But the problem is the (IN IMAGE) Machine Types and Mother board Reports are at the same level,but i want to show different icon for Machine Type(i want folder icon) and Motherboard report (file icon).Actually i am generating this structure from database using web.site map.

My Treeview code in aspx file is as follows.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
        <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/TreeView/images/folder/folder.gif" />
        <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/TreeView/images/folder/folder.gif" />
        <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/TreeView/images/folder/file.gif" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

So Can Any body help me out..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ImageUrl property of each node to achieve it :
for eg:

```
<asp:TreeNode ImageUrl="image.jpg"></asp:TreeNode>
```

Comment: I need to do every thing from code behind only..I am generating this tree view from code behind means First i am creating a dynamic web.sitemap file from database table and then attaching it to tree view using sitemap datasource control.@Srinivas